# Getting 500 Internal Server Error instead of 404 Not Found Error

Tags: .htaccess

So when I was testing my website which is hosted on Bluehost, I wanted to test out my 404.html which was going well. However, I then noticed that I keep getting the default 500 internal server error from Bluehost when I typed something like this, https://www.example.com/folder/webpage/awdawdasd (basically putting a slash after the webpage name and typing random things). In my htaccess, I made it so that it allows users to visit the website without the .html at the back, i.e. hides the extension in the URL. How can I fix it so that when the user type random things after the html page like shown in the example?

Note that I am using Bluehost's file manager only, i.e. hosting my own html pages on Bluehost that I have coded as part of my assignment, I am not using Wordpress or anything.

Here is my htaccess code,

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.

<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
  
  # Prevent user from going to the website's index
  Options -Indexes

</IfModule>

## EXPIRES HEADER CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On

 # Images
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

  # Video
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"

  # Fonts
  ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"

  # CSS, JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

  # Others
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
  
</IfModule>

## REWRITE RULES
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  
  # Redirects user from http to https
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
  
  # Allow browsers to access webpages without .html at the end
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

  # Redirect user to webpage url without .html if they typed .html in the url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
  RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
  
  # Removes .php extension
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

  # Redirect user to webpage url without .php if they typed .php in the url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
  
  # Redirect users to the error webpages if user receives a 404 error, etc.
  ErrorDocument 401 /errorpages/401
  ErrorDocument 403 /errorpages/403
  ErrorDocument 404 /errorpages/404
  ErrorDocument 500 /errorpages/500
  ErrorDocument 502 /errorpages/502
  ErrorDocument 503 /errorpages/503
  
  # End of Apache Rewrite Rules
</IfModule>

# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

[Bluehost 500 Internal Server Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67me5.jpg)

Edit: I have contacted Bluehost and was able to deduce that it was not from their side but the problem lies in the code above. I have also edited the apache rewrite code to redirect users if they type in .html at the back.

Update: Managed to find the error logs and it says

```
/home2/otakuabr/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
```

Comment: So what actual issue do you see in the http server's error log?

Comment: Update: I got a bad flag delimiter error for the rewrite rules

Comment: Usually that error messages indicates stray whitespace characters in your rule set. I cannot spot any, though. Maybe you have other, faults rules in place somewhere else? Or maybe you did not copy your rule set 1:1? Also check if you have some other, non printable whitespace charater somewhere instead of a standard space character. Best is to track the culprit down by commenting out sections one by one and making a test request to see which rule actually throws the error.

Comment: May I know what is a rule set 1:1? Additionally, I have copied and pasted the whole code from my .htaccess. Though I have used http://www.htaccesscheck.com/index.html to check my .htaccess for any syntax errors but results did not show any errors.

Comment: "copying something 1:1" refers to the act of creating an exact copy instead of copying only parts or altering something along the way.

Comment: I assume you have some other rules somewhere which contain the error.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have copied it 1:1, the rewrite rule I copied is from https://tecadmin.net/remove-file-extension-from-url-using-htaccess/ . The others are definitely copied 1:1 too.

Comment: So that leaves rules implemented elsewhere (other distributed configuration files or in the central configuration of the http server's host configuration) or a non-space whitespace character in your rules.

Comment: Did you try to single out the rule that actually throws the error? As recommended above? What is the outcome?

Comment: Yep and managed to find the problem, the problem lies in the rewrite code from that tecadmin website, I managed to find a solution by using this code from this website: https://techwebs.in/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess It is probably because the rewrite code will force it to redirect the browser to the one without the extension name and if you were to put a slash after it, an error 500 will pop up. Thanks for the much-appreciated help!

Comment: That does not really explain the error message you received. But anyway, fine if you managed to solve your issue.